# Out of Memory in Charset Encoding

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

I have a very large `ByteBuffer` that is about several MB in size. And when I run the `ByteBuffer` in

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(new File(decodedUri)).getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
CharBuffer cb;
if (encoding == null)
    encoding = "UTF-8";
cb = Charset.forName(encoding).decode(bb);
```

I get an `OutOfMemoryError` every other time where the stack trace can be traced to `Charset.decode`. It was this line that triggered the error.

```
cb = Charset.forName(encoding).decode(bb);
```

How do I fix this?

Because the first time the app is started OutOfMemoryError does not get triggered, and only the second time I tried to start it, this error occurs.  I was wondering if there is some sort of flush out of the buffer I need to do?  Or something similar?

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace?

Comment: It would be quite difficult.  This is an Android txt reading app that gets to be started upon clicking the txt file.  So I couldn't test it on emulator but had to test on Android phone.

Comment: @JasonChing - do you need to have access to the entire decoded file at once? Using a `CharsetDecoder` and reading chunks from the file to feed it with will allow you to process the file in increments instead.

Comment: @Jens- I think that will work.  Do you know how to read in a file in increments using FileChannel?  Or is there a better way? Like RandomAccessFile maybe?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read that huge file in chunks you can do it like this with an `AsyncTask`:

```
static class StreamTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    private static final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 1024 * 8; // Adjust to taste

    // Param #0 = file name
    // Param #1 = charset name
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (params.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        int chars = 0;
        CharsetDecoder cd = Charset.forName(params[1]).newDecoder();
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(params[0]);
            try {
                FileChannel fc = fin.getChannel();
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFFER_LENGTH);
                CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_LENGTH);

                while (fc.read(bb) != -1) {
                    // Flip the buffer, decode the contents
                    bb.flip();
                    cd.decode(bb, cb, false); // You should probably look at CoderResult also.
                    // Flip & extract the decoded characters.
                    cb.flip();
                    chars += cb.remaining();
                    onCharacters(cb.array(), cb.position(), cb.remaining());
                    cb.clear();
                    // Prepare the buffer for reuse.
                    bb.compact();
                }

                // fc.read(..) returned -1 -> EOF, but bb may still contain
                // stuff to decode.
                bb.flip();
                cd.decode(bb, cb, true);
                cd.flush(cb);
                cb.flip();
                if (cb.remaining() > 0) {
                    chars += cb.remaining();
                    onCharacters(cb.array(), cb.position(), cb.remaining());
                }
            } finally {
                fin.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            chars = -1;
        }
        return chars;
    }


    protected void onCharacters(char[] ch, int offset, int length) {
        // Do something with the characters (still running in the AsyncTask thread)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jens!  Can you show me how to decode the ByteBuffer, say as BIG5?

Comment: Hm? This example would decode to whatever charset you pass it, e.g. `new StreamTask().execute("path/to/your/big5textfile.txt", "big5");` The second parameter you pass to `execute` is the name of the character set.